Question on the Proof of Proposition 6.6 in the Book Introduction to Lie Algebras by Karin Erdmann and Mark J. Wildon
I have yet another question around Engel's theorem, this time on the Proof of Proposition 6.6 near the end of page 50 of Book "Introduction to Lie Algebras" by Karin and Mark.
The Proposition 6.6 states that

Let $V$ be a non-zero complex vector space. Suppose that $L$ is a solvable Lie subalgebra of $gl(V)$. Then there is some non-zero $v \in V$ which is a simultaneous eigenvector for all $x \in L$.

By applying the inductive hypothesis, we arrive at a vector $w \in V$, a simultaneous eigenvector for all $a \in A$. $A$ is solvable. We also have the weight space defined as $V_{\lambda} = \{v \in V: a(v) = \lambda(a)v, \space \forall a \in A \}$
And $A$ was chosen such that $L = A \oplus Span\{z\}$, with $z \in L$, and $z \ne 0$.
The proof then uses Invariance Lemma (Lemma 5.5) to prove the existence of non-zero $v \in V_{\lambda}$ for eigenvector for $z$. This part I don't understand.
Lemma 5.5 states that

Assume that $F$ has characteristic zero. Let $L$ be a Lie subalgebra of $gl(V)$ and let $A$ be an ideal of $L$. Let $\lambda: A \rightarrow F$ be a weight of $A$. The associated weight space
$V_\lambda = \{v \in V: av = \lambda(a)v, \forall a \in A \}$
is an $L$-invariant subspace of V.

From Lemma 5.5, I can see that if $z \in L$, then $a(zv) = z(av) = \lambda(a)zv$, thus $zv$ is also a eigenvector for $a$, where $a \in A$. I don't see the connection of it with eigenvector of $z$ in $V$. Could someone enlighten me on this one, thanks!
Why would Invariance Lemma indicate the existence of eigenvector in the weight space for some $z$ outside of $A$?


From Lemma 5.5, I can see that if $z \in L$, then $a(zv) = z(av) = \lambda(a)zv$, thus $zv$ is also a eigenvector for $a$, where $a \in A$. I don't see the connection of it with eigenvector of $z$ in $V$.

this calculation is beside the point. Lemma 5.5 tells you $V_\lambda$ is $L$-invariant, so it is $z$-invariant, so $z$ induces a linear map $V_\lambda \to V_\lambda$. Complex linear maps on non-zero finite-dimensional vector spaces always have eigenvectors. Hence $z$ has an eigenvector in $V_\lambda$.  This eigenvector is a simultaneous eigenvector for all $x \in L$.
